# Can you short a stock before the ex-div. date to make a profit?

Tags: investing, shorting-securities, ex-dividend-date

If the price of a share automatically declines the same amount as the dividend on the ex-div. date why don't people short the stock right before the ex-date and then when the share price drops relative to the div. payout cover the short and make a profit.  Example, shares of Company A are trading at $10.00 a share on Dec 2, Gordon Gekko decides to short the stock. On Dec 3 the stock goes ex-div. and Company A is paying a 10% div or $1.00 per share.  Because of this the stock opens at $9.00 a share to reflect the dividend.  Why can't GG cover the short at $9.00 and walk away with a $1.00 per share profit? Is this illegal or is there some regulation to prevent this?

Answer (score 15):

When you short a stock and the stock goes ex-div. you have to pay out an amount equal to the dividend. So in your example, GG would short the stock at $10.00, buy back at $9.00 and be charged $1.00 for the dividend. Net effect $0.00.

Comment: Yes and in effect, since one is *borrowing* the stock from someone who *would have* received the dividend payment, one needs to make an equivalent payment to them to keep them whole. If it weren't so, there wouldn't be stock available for shorts to borrow.